# BeautifulSoup Django Parse for Links

Tags: python, django, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the links `a` with `class=fl` I'm using mechanize to get the raw html output and then beautifulsoup to try to parse out the links.

The value of `rawGatheredGoogleOutput` is outputting output like (which is just a google result):
The red portion is to show you what I'm trying to grab, which is the `a.fl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find `a` elements with a `class=fl` attribute, you call `find_all` like this:

```
getAdditionalGooglePages = beautifulSoupObj.find_all('a', attrs={"class": "fl"})
```

For other attributes, it's simpler - for example, with `id=fl` it would be:

```
getAdditionalGooglePages = beautifulSoupObj.find_all('a', id="fl")
```

... but that doesn't work with `class`, because it's a Python reserved word.

Comment: Does find_all() find all links that match this? Is it better to use find_all() compared to doing a loop?

Comment: @CodeTalk yes, it should return a list containing all the matched elements.

Comment: How can I control the href? For instance, find_all() links with href that contains 'start= ' somewhere in the href value ?  Is there someway to use regex ?

Comment: @CodeTalk yes, `find_all('a', href=some_regex)` works too. The [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc) is very good, by the way - you should give it a read.

Comment: I checked that out and came up with: `find_all('a',attrs={'class':'fl', 'href':'^.*start='})` . This doesn't match a string like: `site:thesite.com&hl=en&ei=zBgMUpj5I_TC4APproHQCQ&start=10&`   . Any idea?

Comment: `'^.*start='` isn't a regex, it's a string - try `pattern = re.compile('^.*start=')` and `attrs={'class': 'fl', 'href': pattern}` (note the lack of quotes - you want to pass a regex *object*).

Comment: You have been instrumental in helping me  - I have learned quite a bit! Thank you!